# Trying to write a file in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem trying to write in java (using windows) data with this code, where I create a directory (effectively is created) but when a it comes to create the file it fails

```
String rutaescribir="C"
        + ":"
        + "\\"
        + "Users\\EmanuelJosé\\Desktop\\Cplexjava\\memoria\\java"
        + numesc + "esc\\";

Writer writer5=null;// si lo usas acuerdate de cerrarlo
java.io.File directorio5 = new File(rutaescribir+"inf");
directorio5.mkdir();
String directorio523=rutaescribir+"inf\\";          
try {
    writer5 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(directorio523+"inf"+num+".txt"), "utf-8"));
    writer5.write(numesc+"\r\n");
    writer5.write("hola");

}
} catch (IOException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {writer5.close();} catch (Exception ex) {//ignore}
    }
}
```

In the same code I have other files to write, but they work and I look for any  differences, but it's the same...here is an example of one working

```
Writer writer =null;//

java.io.File directorio1 = new File(rutaescribir+"heuristica");
String directorio12=rutaescribir+"heuristica\\";
directorio1.mkdir();
try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(directorio12+"heuristica"+num+".txt"), "utf-8"));
    writer.write(numesc+"\r\n");        

}
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    // report
} finally {
    try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {//ignore}
    }
}
```

I really see no difference...and i don't know why some of them works and other ones don't....Help please!

The error I get is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\EmanuelJosé\Desktop\Cplexjava\memoria\java3esc\infactiblidades\infactib‌​ilidades0.txt (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at memoria.bosques.imprimirenarchivos2(bosques.java:19758)
```

So the file is not created, but why? At least I see the folder exists.

Comment: Are you geting an error? could you post a stack trace if you are.

Comment: He's probably not getting an error because mkdir() doesn't throw one. I'm betting the directory doesn't get created. If he used mkdirs() instead, it'd probably work. I'm guessing some of them work because the parent directories exist, and some of them fail because the parent directories don't.

Comment: Can you use ex.printStackTrace() to replace System.out.println("ERRORR!!!!") ? Then you can see what the underline problem is.

Comment: the error i get is: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\EmanuelJosé\Desktop\Cplexjava\memoria\java3esc\infactiblidades\infactibilidades0.txt (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at memoria.bosques.imprimirenarchivos2(bosques.java:19758)
 So the file isn't create, but why, at least i see the folder exist

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the line

```
directorio5.mkdir();
```

to

```
directorio5.mkdirs();
```

This ensures that all directories in the path structure are created. using `mkdir()` only creates the very last directory in the path. You're also not testing the return from `mkdir()` to check that the directory was actually created, i.e.

```
if (directario5.exists() || directario5.mkdirs()){
    // Go ahead, because our directory is now guaranteed to exist.
}
```

Comment: `mkdir(s)` will return `false` if the directories already exists ;)

Comment: Thanks, i realized my mistake with the if you recommended ;)